# Eclipse -> Option "Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk." missing

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently trying the AWS tutorial here https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/deploying-a-sample-skill-as-a-web-service#h3_deployEB

Afaik I did all the steps before correct, but if I try the step two: "In the Eclipse Project Explorer, right-click the project and click Amazon Web Services then Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk."

There is no option **Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk**, I only have the options Run function on AWS Lambda and Upload function to AWS lambda.

Any ideas what is missing here? The Maven project compiles fine and I already have the warfile.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bug but it works like this:

When I right click one of my ".jar" projects, I cannot see the option:

[image]

Bu when I right click one of my "war" (maven web app) projects I can see the deployment option:

[image]

Maybe you should deploy a war file?

***Edit:*** Maybe you must try after building the project? The plugin is maybe searching for the appropriate file type (.war) to deploy.